# SQL Azure: Deadlock on concurrent delete operations

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am encountering some deadlocks on my SQL azure database caused by concurrent delete operations and I am unsure as how to resolve it. I have simplified the situation to the most basic level. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test2013](
    [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [dbo-Test2013] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientID] ASC,
    [ID] ASC
)
 WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
       IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
       ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test2013] ADD CONSTRAINT [Test2013-ID-Default-Value]
     DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ID]
GO
```

The query that causes the issue is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [Test2013]
    ([ClientID],[ID],[Value])
    SELECT
        CAST(-2147483648 AS INT) [ClientID], 
        '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de088' [ID], 
        CAST(1 AS INT) [Value]

INSERT INTO [Test2013]
    ([ClientID],[ID],[Value])
    SELECT
        CAST(-2147483648 AS INT) [ClientID], 
        '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de077' [ID], 
        CAST(2 AS INT) [Value]

 DECLARE @MyDateTime DATETIME
SET @MyDateTime = DATEADD(s,5,GETDATE())

DECLARE @MyDateTime2 DATETIME
SET @MyDateTime2 = DATEADD(ms,1,@MyDateTime)

BEGIN tran
    WAITFOR TIME @MyDateTime;
    DELETE FROM [Test2013]
    WHERE [ID] = '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de088';
Commit tran

BEGIN tran
    WAITFOR TIME @MyDateTime2;
    DELETE FROM [Test2013]
    WHERE [ID] = '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de077';
Commit tran
```

I thought this would be relatively trivial but I cannot find out what is actually locking on the query. I have checked the sys.events_log table and it doesn't contain any new deadlock events. I have seen other deadlocks before, but they all threw Exceptions that I could handle, this one just hangs indefinitely.

On a side note, if I delay the second operation by 50 ms, it works fine.

Comment: Only a comment but did you try a "go" after each insert?

Comment: Well... Derp. That was dumb. Yes, it works now. Still doesn't work in my more complicated version but that's my issue (probably a trigger putting a lock somewhere i didn't expect).

Comment: @Blam: How exactly does `GO` help here?

Comment: That did fix the issue, but why, I do not know. However, if I create a a foreign key on Test2013 to any table, say Test2013_2, the same query fails still.

Answer (score 0):

The hanging here isn't really caused by deadlocks, but because you are waiting for a time that has already passed. Below is a modified version of your query that spams the current time along with the messages from my run. As you can see, by the time you are waiting for @MyDateTime2, it has already passed. The reason why 50 ms works is because it doesn't take 50 ms to do all that work. I changed WAITFOR TIME to WAITFOR DELAY, and it works. It doesn't really wait for a millisecond, though.

```
INSERT INTO [Test2013]
    ([ClientID],[ID],[Value])
    SELECT
        CAST(-2147483648 AS INT) [ClientID], 
        '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de088' [ID], 
        CAST(1 AS INT) [Value]

INSERT INTO [Test2013]
    ([ClientID],[ID],[Value])
    SELECT
        CAST(-2147483648 AS INT) [ClientID], 
        '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de077' [ID], 
        CAST(2 AS INT) [Value]

 DECLARE @MyDateTime DATETIME
SET @MyDateTime = DATEADD(s,5,GETDATE())

PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, @MyDateTime, 121))
DECLARE @MyDateTime2 DATETIME
SET @MyDateTime2 = DATEADD(ms,1,@MyDateTime)

PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, @MyDateTime2, 121))
BEGIN tran
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    WAITFOR TIME @MyDateTime;
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    DELETE FROM [Test2013] 
    WHERE [ID] = '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de088';
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
Commit tran

BEGIN tran
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    WAITFOR TIME @MyDateTime2;
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    DELETE FROM [Test2013]
    WHERE [ID] = '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de077';
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
Commit tran
```

Resulting messages when I cancel the query:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
2013-06-21 15:13:09.980
2013-06-21 15:13:09.980
2013-06-21 15:13:04.980
2013-06-21 15:13:09.997

(1 row(s) affected)
2013-06-21 15:13:09.997
2013-06-21 15:13:10.017
Query was cancelled by user.
```

Using WAITFOR DELAY instead:    INSERT INTO [Test2013]
        ([ClientID],[ID],[Value])
        SELECT
            CAST(-2147483648 AS INT) [ClientID], 
            '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de088' [ID], 
            CAST(1 AS INT) [Value]

```
INSERT INTO [Test2013]
    ([ClientID],[ID],[Value])
    SELECT
        CAST(-2147483648 AS INT) [ClientID], 
        '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de077' [ID], 
        CAST(2 AS INT) [Value]


BEGIN tran
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    WAITFOR delay '00:00:05'
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    DELETE FROM [Test2013] 
    WHERE [ID] = '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de088';
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
Commit tran

BEGIN tran
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    WAITFOR delay '00:00:00.001'
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
    DELETE FROM [Test2013]
    WHERE [ID] = '82ecb924-d2f0-44ee-9a8e-5240d12de077';
PRINT(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 121))
Commit tran
```